# Error with version in Flutter depencies with dialogflow, firebase_auth and http

Tags: firebase, flutter, http, dialogflow-es

Hello to everyone and thank's to everyone who can help me.
I've this error with a Flutter projet :

> Because flutter_dialogflow >=0.1.3 depends on http ^0.12.0+2 and code depends on http ^0.13.0, flutter_dialogflow >=0.1.3 is forbidden.
> So, because code depends on flutter_dialogflow ^0.1.3, version solving failed.
> pub get failed (1; So, because code depends on flutter_dialogflow ^0.1.3, version solving failed.)

This error came after added dialogflow. I tried to change different version and ask the community but without success.

Can anyone help me please ?

My pubspec.yaml dependencies:

```
flutter:
  sdk: flutter

flutter_localizations:
  sdk: flutter

http: ^0.13.0
shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
numberpicker: ^2.0.0
firebase_core: ^1.1.0
firebase_auth: ^1.1.0
json_annotation: ^3.1.1
url_launcher: ^6.0.3
toast: ^0.1.5
charts_flutter: ^0.10.0
syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: ^19.1.56-beta
flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0+3
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.0
flutter_native_timezone: ^1.0.10
flutter_dialogflow: ^0.1.3`
```

Comment: try `http: ^0.12.0+2`, if it didn't work then there is no solution `dialogflow` isn't maintained

Comment: This causes errors with the firebase_auth package

Comment: I found a solution by upgrading each dependencies and upgrading my version of the flutter sdk.

Comment: Nice! someone opened the same issue but on Github that's why I said there is no solution (https://github.com/VictorRancesCode/flutter_dialogflow/issues/35)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by upgrading each dependencies and upgrading my version of the flutter sdk. (Tools --> Flutter --> Flutter Upgrade) in Intellij